# Flex not doing columns properly in Chrome

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a form whose fields should fall on two columns. I decided to try and use flex boxes to achieve the effect.

HTML :

```
<form class="hbspt-form">
    <fieldset class="form-columns-2">
        <div class="hs_firstname field hs-form-field">...</div>
        <div class="hs_lastname field hs-form-field">...</div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

CSS :

```
form {
    display:flex;
    max-width: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

form fieldset {
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:row nowrap;
    justify-content:space-between;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width:0;
}

form fieldset .field.hs-form-field {
    clear:none;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    float:left;
    min-width:0;
    width:45%;
}

form fieldset.form-columns-2 .field.hs-form-field {
    flex-basis:calc(50% - 1rem);
}
```

And here's what it gives. The div.field's refuse to display as columns, they stubbornly each fall on their separate lines. When I hover the element in DevTools, it looks like an artificial margin-right is created to fill the row, forcing the next div on another line.

[image: Screenshot from Chrome]

This only happens on Chrome (I have version 60.0). On Firefox and Edge, it goes on two columns as expected.

Thanks for your input !

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].